# Restoring HTTP access configuration in ZyXEL VMG1312-B30B

Tags: networking, router

I was home-hosting a web-server and I needed port 80. Port 80 was however taken by the router configuration's web-page. I disabled that webpage, and now the only way to access the router configuration is through telnet.

I do manage to log into the telnet interface, but I don't know where the configuration for remote access is.

From the telnet interface, can I re-enable the web interface? Can I also change the web interface port from 80, to say 8080?

---

The help command prints out some commands. I will list those that might be related to this, and those that I don't know the function of.

```
wlctld
sipalgctl
btt
```

Comment: You could try typing things like help and version and try to find out what operating system it is.  That would be very very interesting, though the easy boring alternative is to do a full reset on the device. Zyxel  do have a telephone number if you can't figure out how to do the hard reset.  Also, you may have the telephone cable  plugged into the wall with a Zyxel if there's a modem in there i.e. if it uses a telephone cable.

Comment: @barlop Help returns some commands. Some more familiar than others. I'll probably list some, in case they do relate to remote access. Version is an unknown command

Comment: you can look up the CLI or telnet guides for some routers  perhaps this may help, it's for A model of Zyxel ftp://ftp.zyxel.co.uk/P-660HN-F1/cli_reference_guide/P-660HN-F1_1.pdf  or ftp://ftp.zyxel.com/ISG50-PSTN/cli_reference_guide/ISG50-PSTN_1.pdf

Comment: I don't see any CLI guide for  your model `ftp://ftp.zyxel.com/VMG1312-B10A/`    Whereas this model for example has a CLI guide  `ftp://ftp.zyxel.co.uk/P-660HN-F1/`, though maybe some commands are the same. You could call Zyxel and ask them..

Comment: @barlop Would dumping config on the same router with web config, and changing some areas on the non-web-config router work? I could also use tftp to put files onto the router. Since the router looks UNIX-like, would nano work?

Comment: i've got no idea but no harm in trying. I guess a full reset should reverse things and  prove that after adding a file, it gets removed .. so it'd show that it's reversible to change anything.

Comment: @barlop It should, but I will leave the full reset to the end, and see if I can do otherwise. Putting nano on is a subject to testing then

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44293/discussion-between-barlop-and-thebro21).

Comment: I ended up here for my VMG1312 (Stuck in the same place), this appears to be a more appropriate CLI manual for this device: https://support.aa.net.uk/images/6/6c/VMG1312-B10A_CLI_Reference_Manual.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Log in with either SSH or telnet, whichever one is still available and then try with this command

```
rmtmgmt config --proto http --lan enable --wan disable --trust disable
```

The `rmtmgmt` has a short help, so you might want to modify the command to your needs.

You can then change the port either by using `rmtmgmt` or through http interface

This was tested on VMG1312-B30A but hopefully it's the same for B30B